# Access elements from two sublist without using a nested for loop in python

Tags: python, list, nested-loops

for example :

```
list = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]]
```

and I want to compare the first element of two consecutive sublists in every iteration of for loop.
How should I write the for loop?

I have tried this following code :

```
for x in list:
    print(x[0])
    print(x+1[0])
```

I know the use of (`x+1[0]`) is completely illogical. But what should I use at this place? Any suggestions? 
Like comparing(any type of mathematical comparison) 1st elements of list1 & list2, list3 & list4.

Comment: what is ur expected output?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. You say you want to `compare the first element of two sublists`. You have three sublists? Which two do you want to compare? Compare for what? equality? What should the result be? A list of booleans?

Comment: @MarkMeyer here I am not looking for a specific output. Its just a demo example.  I want to understand how can we access two elements of two different sublists in a single iteration without using nested for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zip()` to pair off consecutive lists by passing slices to zip. To pair them off at an offset like: `[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3]` you could use:

```
zip(l, l[1:])
```

To pair them off as pairs (rather than repeating the last one like `[0, 1], [2, 3]`) you could use:

```
zip(l[::], [1:1])
```

In your example that would look like:

```
l = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]]

for l1, l2 in zip(l[::2], l[1::2]):
    print(l1[0], l2[0])
```

Prints:

```
1 5
9 13
```

Comment: this is not an answer to the question

Comment: @InfinityTM there's a checkmark on it which suggests it is.

Comment: And how is this an answer? this doesn't check for same elements

Comment: @InfinityTM read the last comment. The OP just wants to access consecutive sublists in the list (without nests loops). The question is still a little ambiguous — so there's room for different answers. One thing that's not ambitious — they want to do it without nested loops.

Comment: @InfinityTM  Sorry for the ambiguous question. My main motive was to understand how to access elements from sublists in every iteration without using nested for loop. and Mark's answer is the perfect solution for the same.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Just clarifying

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
for x in list1:
    for y in list1:
        if x[0] == y[0]:
            print(x[0],y[0])
```

Now if you don't want to compare the same elements (which the above code does):

```
for x in list1:
    for y in [i for i in list1 if i!=x]:
        if x[0] == y[0]:
            print(x[0],y[0])
```

Or you could print like:

```
for x in list1:
    for y in [i for i in list1 if i!=x]:
        if x[0] == y[0]:
            print(x ,"and", y , 'have the same elements first')
```

Here:

```
list1 = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]]
```

Comment: This will work perfectly, but I want this same functionality without using nested for loop.

Comment: let me try. but that wasn't what the question asked for. so choose this as your answer so that the question is closed. i'll update this aswer with a non=nested loop too, if possible

Answer (score 0):

following code will genrate first element from every sublist. Tweak it according to your need

```
lst = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]]

for i in range(len(lst[0])):
    for j in range(len(lst)):
        print(lst[j][i], end=" ")
    print()
```

Comment: I appreciate your effort but I wanted to do this without nested loop.